# Wrong page numbers in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I'm loosing my mind over the page numbering of my table of Contents in my Thesis. I need both, roman and arabic numbers for my Table of content which should Look like this:

```
 List of Tables    i
 List of Figures   ii
 Introduction      1
 .
 .
 .
 References        iii
 Appendix          iv
```

However, somehow get

```
 List of Tables    i
 List of Figures   i
 Introduction      1 (good)
 .
 .                  (all good)
 .
 References        i
 Appendix          vii
```

all arabic numbers are fine but everything else is messen up...
Here some of my code:

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{report}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{titlesec}
  \titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
  \usepackage{appendix}
  \usepackage[a4paper, left=30mm, right=30mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}

 begin{document}

 \input{Chapters/Titlepage}
 \chapter*{Abstract}
 \thispagestyle{empty}

 \newpage
 \tableofcontents
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \newpage
 \pagenumbering{roman}
 \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}

 \newpage
 \pagenumbering{roman}
 \listoftables
 \newpage
 \listoffigures

 \newpage
 \clearpage
 \pagenumbering{arabic}
 \chapter{Introduction}
 \input{Chapters/Introduction}

 \chapter{Theoretical Framework}
 \input{Chapters/Theoretical Framework}

  etc.

 \newpage
 \pagenumbering{roman}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
 \printbibliography

 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
 \input{Chapters/Appendix}
```

Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: When you do `\pagenumbering{roman}` at the end the page counter is reset. You could set it manually, but I've never seen such a bad style for a table of contents.

Comment: you have not provided an example that anyone can run to see the issue, but note that with `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}`  you are adding entries to the  table of contents with no connection to the page where the list of figures actually appears so there is no reason to expect it to reference the page with the list of figures. You do this for list of tables at the same place so naturally the two entries show the same page number.

Comment: you shouldn't use the same numbering style at the begin and the end of the document. How should the reader know where to look for page iii in such a document?